# What is the name & solution for this 33-piece 3D wooden puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles, solvability

I purchased this 3D wooden puzzle and wasn't provided with the instructions to reassemble it. I can't seem to find any information about it other than the source I bought it from.
It has 33 pieces

Does anyone know any information about it? Common name or even the solution?

[image: 3D Wooden puzzle 33 pieces]
[image: Separate pieces]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Thanks for including so much information in your post - that was very helpful for tracking down the puzzle. (Also, we've edited your post to make it slightly more findable for anyone who has the same question later - hope you don't mind!)

Comment: I'm a little confused... Is it that you've demolished it and are having trouble putting it back together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be the [Hercules](https://www.puzzlewarehouse.com/Hercules-Cube-Medium-142168.html) burr puzzle. (It may also be known as [Diamond #33](https://kubiyagames.com/diamond-33-challenging-burr-puzzle); I can't tell if theirs is the same, because they claim to have 9 different shapes but they also don't cut the corners.)

There is a solution from the manufacturer of the Hercules puzzle available [here](http://www.craftypuzzles.com/puzzles/hercules.html).

In case the link goes down, here is the image they give:

> [image]